# Understanding input value in JavaScript memoized function

Tags: javascript, memoization

I am currently going through 'Javascript: The good parts' by Douglas Crockford, an there is an example demonstrating the concept of memoization.

```
var memoizer = function (memo, fundamental) {
  var shell = function (n) {
   var result = memo[n];
   if (typeof result !== 'number') {
     result = fundamental(shell, n);
     memo[n] = result;
   }
  return result;
  };
return shell;
};

var fibonacci = memoizer([0, 1], function (shell, n) {
   return shell(n - 1) + shell(n - 2);
});
```

What I don't understand is, where is the value for `n` coming from?

Comment: have a look here for another good example of js memoization: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578831/doubts-on-javascript-apply-function-memoization

Comment: I would edit this to remove the tags from the title... but then it'd be empty. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: @liath, sorry about the title.. You are absolutely right. Well the question is pretty stupid, and not really about memoization. However I needed help understanding what is happening in this specific memoization example..

Comment: @user2678538 no worries, typically a title about the problem rather than the techs helps to attract answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660912/javascript-closure-questions) or [Explanation on “JavaScript - the Good Parts” example (section 4.15)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798858/explanation-on-javascript-the-good-parts-example-section-4-15)

Comment: @Bergi this is in fact an exactduplicate. Sorry for that. And it also has quite a useful answer! cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code `var shell = function (n)`, you're specifying that when you call the function `shell`, you're going to provide it with an input argument `n`. So if you called `shell(5)`, `n` would be equal to 5, or any other number that you passed in.

You need to look at what's being called and returned in each function call -- `fibonacci` is set to the returned value of the `memoizer` function, and `memoizer` returns the `shell` function which takes in `n`. So although it's never called in your example code, in the end you'd call, say, `fibonacci(5)` where 5 is your `n`. Just follow the function calls and returns.

Comment: Yes sure I am quite aware that upon invocation, the function shell would receive n value.. However, I got confused as to when the `n` is passed in this example. Basically, to verify that I am not loosing my mind.. So for this to work, do I need to invoke the memoizer function at some point ?

Comment: @user2678538: No, the *memoized* function. You are already invoking `memoizer()` when creating the `fibonacci` function.

Comment: You need to look at what's being created -- `fibonacci` is set to the returned value of the `memoizer` function, and `memoizer` returns the shell function which takes in `n`. So in the end you'd call `fibonacci(5)` where 5 is your `n`. Just follow the function calls and returns.

Answer (score 1):

`n` is an input. It doesn't "come" from any where in the code you've posted, you have to supply it a value.

Comment: Yes sure I am quite aware that upon invocation, the function shell would receive n value.. However, I got confused as to when the `n` is passed in this example. Basically, to verify that I am not loosing my mind.. So for this to work, do I need to invoke the memoizer function at some point ?

Comment: @user2678538: He's trying to tell you that in this example no `n` is passed, since you don't call `fibonacci` anywhere (though `shell` is called twice).